# Unable to select from auto complete Cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

[the auto-select for auto complete field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQF6p.png)

```
it('Test to grab the autocomplete values', ()=> {
    cy.visit('https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/');
    cy.get('#tags').type('c')
        cy.get('#ui-id-2').first().click()
    })
})
```

it shows that it was clicked but it does't get chosen

Comment: Idk cypress at all, but I think this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831736/how-to-select-cypress-autocomplete-field

Answer (score 1):

Your code is basically ok, but you need to execute within the `iframe`

```js
cy.visit('https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/')
cy.get('iframe.demo-frame')
  .its('0.contentDocument.body')
  .within(() => {

    cy.get('#tags').type('c')
    cy.get('#ui-id-2').first().click()
    cy.get('#tags').should('have.value', 'ActionScript')
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I could see there is an iframe, for dealing with iframe you have to use the code:

```js
cy.get('iframe.demoframe').its('0.contentDocument').its('body')
```

So your code should look like:

```js
cy.visit('https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/')
cy.get('iframe.demo-frame')
  .its('0.contentDocument')
  .its('body')
  .find('#tags')
  .type('c')
cy.get('iframe.demo-frame')
  .its('0.contentDocument')
  .its('body')
  .find('li')
  .first()
  .click()
```

Now if you want to further condense your script you can use Cypress Custom commands. Go to `cypress/support/command.js` and write:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframe', (iframe) => {
  return cy
    .get(iframe)
    .its('0.contentDocument.body')
    .should('be.visible')
    .then(cy.wrap)
})
```

And your test will be:

```js
cy.visit('https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/')
cy.getIframe('iframe.demo-frame').find('#tags').type('c')
cy.getIframe('iframe.demo-frame').find('li').first().click()
```